# What's making these mathematically equivalent floating point equations give different answers?

Tags: c, compilation, floating-point

So I know computers aren't especially 'good' at handling floats in many languages. I've seen `0.1 + 0.2` fail quite a few times in different languages. I've also learned that compilers can optimize a bit by evaluating some expressions during compilation. Knowing all that, I ran a little experiment.

Here's some C code I wrote:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float g1 = 0.1;
float g2 = 0.2;

int main() {
  float l1 = 0.1;
  float l2 = 0.2;
  printf("a: %.50f\n", 0.3);
  printf("b: %.50f\n", 0.1 + 0.2);
  printf("c: %.50f\n", (0.1 * 10 + 0.2 * 10) / 10);
  printf("d: %.50f\n", l1 + l2);
  printf("e: %.50f\n", (l1 * 10 + l2 * 10) / 10);
  printf("f: %.50f\n", g1 + g2);
  printf("g: %.50f\n", (g1 * 10 + g2 * 10) / 10);
  return 0;
}
```

Here's its output:

```
a: 0.29999999999999998889776975374843459576368331909180
b: 0.30000000000000004440892098500626161694526672363281
c: 0.29999999999999998889776975374843459576368331909180
d: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
e: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
f: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
g: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
```

It makes complete sense to be that "d," "e," "f" and "g" have the same result. I think "a," "b" and "c" being different from "d," "e," "f" and "g" is because of the difference between compile-time and run-time evaluation. However, I find it strange that "a" and "c" are the same but "b" is different.

Are my current understandings correct? Why are "a" and "c" the same while "b" is different?

Comment: See [Is floating-point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/15168)

Comment: This specific behavior is explained in the answer below. But in general, floating point computation does not correspond to it's "mathematical" counterpart. For instance, the associativity of operations might not hold (like in `(a*b)*c` won't be equal to `a*(b*c)`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was briefly tempted to close this as a duplicate of that; however, then I thought the issue of the constant types and the `f` suffix was (maybe) worth an answer.

Comment: I didn't go dupe-hammering because, although the two are closely related, they are not exact duplicates.

Comment: You might adjust the way you think about this issue.  Me, I'd say that computers *are* quite good at handling floating point.  Expressions like `0.1 + 0.2` do not "fail".  Most of the anomalies and discrepancies and "inaccuracies" you see are due to the fact that the arithmetic is happening in binary, but you're seeing the results after a potentially-lossy conversion back to decimal.

Comment: When we look at floating-point numbers in decimal — which is
of course how we look at them most of the time! — we are looking
at them, in effect, through a slightly bad pair of glasses.
Internally, any floating-point number has a nice, crisp, exact,
binary value, but when we print it out using `%f` to get a decimal
result, we almost always distort it slightly.  It's not that
the underlying floating-point value is "wrong" or "inaccurate"
or "broken" or "bad", it's merely that the lens we're viewing
it though is imperfect.

Comment: ChocolateOverflow, `float` can typically exactly encode about 2^32 different values.  Do you think `0.1` is one of them?  If not, what value do you think `g1` has?

Answer (score 2):

The literal (constant) values specified as arguments to `printf` in your "a", "b" and "c" cases are of type `double`, not `float`. Adding the `f` suffix, to make them `float`, and then running it after compiling with clang-cl gives the same answer for all cases:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

float g1 = 0.1;
float g2 = 0.2;

int main() {
    float l1 = 0.1;
    float l2 = 0.2;
    printf("a: %.50f\n", 0.3f);
    printf("b: %.50f\n", 0.1f + 0.2f);
    printf("c: %.50f\n", (0.1f * 10 + 0.2f * 10) / 10);
    printf("d: %.50f\n", l1 + l2);
    printf("e: %.50f\n", (l1 * 10 + l2 * 10) / 10);
    printf("f: %.50f\n", g1 + g2);
    printf("g: %.50f\n", (g1 * 10 + g2 * 10) / 10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
b: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
c: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
d: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
e: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
f: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
g: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
```

(With your *original* code, the output I get is as you have quoted.)

Now, although `float` arguments to functions with variadic arguments (like `printf`) are promoted to `double`, how the compiler evaluates those expressions will likely be implementation-specific. Adding the explicit `f` suffix will (should?) remove any ambiguity.

Comment: Depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, `0.1f + 0.2f` may evaluate using `double` math and form a different sum.

Answer (score 1):

Most exact decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number with limited precision.

For IEEE 754 double precision format (C `double`), the closest representations of 0.1 and 0.2 are both slightly above the exact decimal value, so their sum is also slightly above the exact decimal sum. However, the closest representable value of 0.3 is slightly below the exact decimal value.

If the C compiler folds constant expressions, it should take the rounding rules into account. It should not replace the decimal expression `0.1 + 0.2` with the decimal constant `0.3` before converting to the binary representation. It should convert `0.1` and `0.2` to their binary representations and sum them to a single binary representation.

The example below illustrates that the output is the same whether the values come from constants or from variables assigned with the same constants (and of the same type as the constants, `double` in this case):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double d1 = 0.1;
    double d2 = 0.2;
    double d3 = 0.3;

    printf("0.1: %.50f\n", 0.1);
    printf("0.2: %.50f\n", 0.2);
    printf("0.1+0.2: %.50f\n", 0.1 + 0.2);
    printf("0.3: %.50f\n", 0.3);
    printf("\n");
    printf("d1: %.50f\n", d1);
    printf("d2: %.50f\n", d2);
    printf("d1+d2: %.50f\n", d1 + d2);
    printf("d3: %.50f\n", d3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.1: 0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045410
0.2: 0.20000000000000001110223024625156540423631668090820
0.1+0.2: 0.30000000000000004440892098500626161694526672363281
0.3: 0.29999999999999998889776975374843459576368331909180

d1: 0.10000000000000000555111512312578270211815834045410
d2: 0.20000000000000001110223024625156540423631668090820
d1+d2: 0.30000000000000004440892098500626161694526672363281
d3: 0.29999999999999998889776975374843459576368331909180
```

Consistency is a good thing!

For the IEEE 754 single precision format (C `float`), the closest representations of 0.1, 0.2, and 0.3 are all slightly above the exact decimal values. As long as we are careful to use the `f` suffix on the constants to make them type `float` instead of `double`, we still get consistent results for expressions using constants and expressions using variables assigned with those constants, as shown below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f1 = 0.1f;
    float f2 = 0.2f;
    float f3 = 0.3f;

    printf("0.1f: %.50f\n", 0.1f);
    printf("0.2f: %.50f\n", 0.2f);
    printf("0.1f+0.2f: %.50f\n", 0.1f + 0.2f);
    printf("0.3f: %.50f\n", 0.3f);
    printf("\n");
    printf("f1: %.50f\n", f1);
    printf("f2: %.50f\n", f2);
    printf("f1+f2: %.50f\n", f1 + f2);
    printf("f3: %.50f\n", f3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0.1f: 0.10000000149011611938476562500000000000000000000000
0.2f: 0.20000000298023223876953125000000000000000000000000
0.1f+0.2f: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
0.3f: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000

f1: 0.10000000149011611938476562500000000000000000000000
f2: 0.20000000298023223876953125000000000000000000000000
f1+f2: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
f3: 0.30000001192092895507812500000000000000000000000000
```